# Azure DevOps Extensions - How configure to my extension displays Control Options > Run This Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions, azure-pipelines-release-task

I am starting with extensions for Azure DevOps, and I have a little problem with default configuration.

I need that my project has "Run this task" option, in Control Options, like all others extensions. I was looking Microsoft official and in other extensions repositories, but I can't found how I can do this.

This configuration is very important to me, to do a rollback when previous task has failed.

Can somebody help me?

#### Expected behaviour

[image]

#### Actual behaviour

[image]

#### My Project

Repository: https://github.com/ThiagoBarradas/rancher-vss-ext
Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ThiagoBarradas.rancher

## SOLVED

To solve this troubles, after many time trying, I just needed to remove `runOs` from my `task.json`.

[image: remove runOs]

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to `task.json`:

```
"groups": [
    {
        "name": "advanced",
        "displayName": "Advanced",
        "isExpanded": false
    }
],
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately not works to me :( I released a new version (1.0.9) from my extension adding your snippet but had no effects.

Comment: @thiagobarradas, i have tried to add the task in extension to my job, it shows the 'Run this task' option. Shayki Abramczyk's response should be right. You may try to refresh the task, or re-install the extension.

Comment: I alright edited my question with found solution. when I try to add the previous sniper, not works. But doing a clean up in all solution and removing odsd4